Curvature in Hyperbolic plane
Please help to understand hyperbolic geodesic curvature in the hyperbolic plane in the Poincaré disk model.
EDIT1:
In the Poincaré disk model we have hyperbolic horocycles: the outer circle is assumed to be of unit radius. The other three circles do not intersect the boundary orthogonally, but tangentially. The middle circle passes through the center of the disk.They have a common curvature $-1$.
For  When Sine-Gordon equation of Chebychev net is twice integrated we get all circles as loci in polar coordinates, and in this way we obtain hyperbolic geodesics with representation:
$$ \alpha^{''}= \sin \alpha; \text{Integrating with }~ \alpha = 2 \psi~, \sin \psi= \frac {r}{d},$$
which are circles of arbitrary diameter $d$ passing through the origin and tangential to $y$ axis. $~\psi$ is angle between polar radial line and the circle, primes are on arc of circles.
Their appearance is like the horocycles in disk model which are not hyperbolic geodesics.
What is the non-zero $ \kappa_{hyperbolic- geodesic}$ as function of radius ( or arc distance) in these circles applicable in both cases?
For horocycles the curvature is $-1$ and for Chebychev Net and Beltrami's model they are of  $0$ curvature.
Trying to reconcile these circles seen in two ways to be the same. Is there another hyperbolic geometry model in two dimensions where they are defined and identified belonging to the same concept?
Thanks in advance.


All these circles are congruent to each other and all have curvature 1.

These are called horocycles.

So please see my edit. I know about horocycles. Thanks a lot for all unifying / distinguishing comments.

As @moisheKohan comments, all three of the circles can be mapped to each other by geometry-preserving automorphisms of the unit disk, namely, elements of
$$
SU(1,1) \;=\; \{g\in SL_2(\mathbb C): g^*Hg=H\}
$$
where $H=\pmatrix{ 1 & 0 \cr 0 & -1}$, acting by linear fractional/Mobius transformations. That group is more-than-transitive on the (open) unit disk, and has been well-studied... (to say the least! :)

For obtaining hyperbolic geodesics: When Sine-Gordon equation of Chebychev net  is twice integrated, we get all circles as loci through the pole in polar coordinates Their appearance is like the horocycles in disk model which are not  geodesics. Trying to reconcile various loci in other models also, however shall edit the question later.
